# How to get number of pending matches with Google Play

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play-services, google-play-games

What is the best way to get the number of pending matches with Google Player Game Services?

I am currently thinking of loading all current matches, filtered by ones that are a) currently my turn pending or b) have an invitation for my pending.

The only way I see to do this, is by using [loadMatchesByStatus](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer.html#loadMatchesByStatus(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20int,%20int[])), but this seems like major overkill, as it will async load *all the match data*, but all I care about is the *number* of matches (I don't actually need any of the match *data*).

Are you aware of anything in the API to provide me with a way to find the number of pending games, without loading all of the game data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to load the 'count' of the matches without loading the rest of the match metadata.

I assume you are using this for some kind of notification badge/alert.  If you are really concerned about performance you could just keep track of this counter locally.  For example increment it whenever you get a turn notification, decrement it when you take a turn, etc.